# Is it possible to add a path to / change the blender plugin directory?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm working on a blender python plugin to be used in Windows 7 and I would like to have it on a shared network location so that the rest of the team doesn't have to constantly pull the plugin to their machine whenever it's updated.

Is there an environment variable or something along the lines of that I can alter to tell blender to look elsewhere for plugins? I've tried searching but I can't find an answer to my question elsewhere.

Comment: You can set a different directory for add-ons in User Preferences > File > Scripts, but if the other artists have custom add-ons on their workstations those would have to be copied over as well. My team uses a rollout of Blender that links the Scripts location to the NAS drives so everyone is pulling from the same central add-on repository.